# Add custom property to all symfony2 controllers

Tags: symfony

is there any way to preprocess controller data somehow. I'm going to take param from session, validate it and assign it as controller property and use it as $this->myVar inside actions of some controller or all of them if possible. Using controller's constructor gives me nothing, I couldn't access request and session data. Thanks!

UPD:
Thanks, [jkucharovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178578/jkucharovic), very good solution.
Also there is a bit dirtier solution, without injecting: setContainer() method, which has been called straight after $controller = new Controller();

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AppServiceController extends Controller {
 private $my_property;

 /**
  * Used as constructor
  */
 public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
 {
    parent::setContainer($container);   
    $this->my_property = 'foo';
    // your controller code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use services in `__construct` method, you have to [inject that services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#core-symfony-and-third-party-bundle-services) first. Then you can use them before any other methods. For example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;

public function __construct(Request $request, Session $session)
{
    …
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am using Symfony2.5 and quite new. When I implement your answer, I get following error `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Fried\FrameworkBundle\Controller\SectionController::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given,`. I believe I might have to pass these through routes. I might be wrong. Can you please guide how can I pass those 2 variables in controller ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you wan't to do is very usefull. A Controller instance will be created each time the controller is called. The session and request will be different each time you call the controller.

I think you should create a `BaseController` class extending `Controller` class with a shortcut method to access your MyVar value in session.

```
class BaseController extends Controller 
{
    public function getMyVar()
    {
        return $this->get('session')->get('MyVarSessionKey');
    }
}
```

All your other Controller will extend from this `BaseController`.

To get the request, just use the shortcut method provided by `Controller` class, `Controller::getRequest()`.